# How to Order received Content Need to show on checkout page?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How to Order received Content Need to show on the checkout page?

Please review below design.

https://www.screencast.com/t/9qbtAmVFj6wX

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a big question so I am only trying to point you to the right direction.
If you have a look at the official WooCommerce docs about payment gateway here:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/payment-gateway-api/
I think what you are looking for falls in either 2 or 3:

> 2. iFrame based – This is when the gateway payment system is loaded
>    inside an iframe on your store. Example: SagePay Form, PayPal Advanced
> 3. Direct – This is when the payment fields are shown directly on the
>    checkout page and the payment is made when ‘place order’ is pressed.
>    Example: PayPal Pro, Authorize.net AIM

more likely 2: iFrame based